# How to silence "Configuration property rebalance_cb is a consumer property and will be ignored by this producer instance"

Tags: docker, nginx, librdkafka, php-rdkafka

I am running a docker container with alpine, nginx and php. On it I have a symfony application running, which is using "flix-tech/avro-serde-php" and "koco/messenger-kafka".
My Docker file looks like this:

```
[...]

ARG LIBRDKAFKA_GIT_SHA1=1f7417d4796e036b8c19f17373f8290ff5c7561f
RUN apk add --update --no-cache alpine-sdk bash python3 autoconf openssl-dev \
  && git clone -o ${LIBRDKAFKA_GIT_SHA1} https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git /tmp/librdkafka \
  && cd /tmp/librdkafka/  \
  && ./configure \
  && make  \
  && make install

# php-rdkafka should be compiled using the same php module as result we are passing
# --with-php-config /usr/local/bin/php-config
ARG PHPCONF_PATH=/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini.d
ARG RDKAFKA_PHP_GIT_SHA1=abd6b6add8e0b983c27245a59981a9a4b5389139
RUN apk add --update --no-cache pcre-dev \
    && pecl install rdkafka

[...]
```

That is all fine and dandy.
However the container is only sending data to kafka, since it is a producer. It isn't a consumer. So when the data is sent to kafka the following bash entry is generated:
`Configuration property rebalance_cb is a consumer property and will be ignored by this producer instance` which then after some steps end up in datadog, my logging system as an error, which it isn't.

So my question is how I can get rid of this message?
Is there a configuration setting, telling the system that it is only a producer? I didn't find the property rebalance_cb anywhere in my project so it is neither part of my code nor of the used libraries. I guess it is part of the compiled librdkafka.

Is there maybe an option to configure the build so that it is only a producer? Or a php.ini setting? I couldn't find anything so far.

Or is there an option for a monolog configuration, which silences such messages?